# Where is the JSON Results from my jQuery AJAX POST Call?

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, http, post

I have this code setup in a web page.

```
    <div id="gridResults">
</div>

<script type="text/ecmascript">
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost:6002/AggregateServices.svc/incident/10",
        type: "POST",
        async: true,
        success:
                function(json) {
                    var table = jQuery('<table />').attr('cellspacing', 0).attr('cellpadding', 4);
                    var header = jQuery('<tr />')
                        .append('<td>Case Number</td>')
                        .append('<td>Company</td>')
                        .append('<td>Created</td>')
                        .append('<td>Description</td>')
                        .append('<td>Stamp</td>')
                        .append('<td>Status</td>')
                        .append('<td>Type</td>');
                    table.append(header);
                    var row = jQuery('<tr/>')
                        .append('<td>' + json.CaseNumber + '</td>')
                        .append('<td>' + json.Company + '</td>')
                        .append('<td>' + json.Created + '</td>')
                        .append('<td>' + json.Description + '</td>')
                        .append('<td>' + json.Stamp + '</td>')
                        .append('<td>' + json.Status + '</td>')
                        .append('<td>' + json.Type + '</td>');
                    table.append(row);
                    jQuery('#gridResults').append(table).show();
                },
        error: function() { alert('An error occurred!'); }
    });
</script>
```

When I run the code I end up with this result.

Simple AJAX Sample with jQuery.

Case Number Company Created Description Stamp   Status  Type
undefined   undefined   undefined   undefined   undefined   undefined   undefined

I checked via Fiddler 2, using POST, to make sure I was getting something back.  The results I see coming back with Fiddler are as follows:

{"CaseNumber":"2","Company":"company","Created":"9/1/2010 6:31:45 PM","Description":"Some description goes here.","Stamp":"/Date(-62135568000000-0800)/","Status":"Stat","Type":"Type"}

So that looks like good JSON?  Anyone have any idea why this isn't parsing?  Or am I missing something else?

TROUBLESHOOTING SO FAR:

I tried to put the row into an append loop, thinking...  not sure what I was thinking, but it didn't help anyway.  What I did was this, the only difference is that it doesn't even give me the "undefined" as I got in the first sample results.

```
jQuery.each(json, function() {
var row = jQuery('<tr/>')
    .append('<td>' + this.CaseNumber + '</td>')
    .append('<td>' + this.Company + '</td>')
    .append('<td>' + this.Created + '</td>')
    .append('<td>' + this.Description + '</td>')
    .append('<td>' + this.Stamp + '</td>')
    .append('<td>' + this.Status + '</td>')
    .append('<td>' + this.Type + '</td>');
table.append(row);});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After fighting back and forth with the code I realized what I had done wrong.  This was in two different projects, a WCF and an ASP.NET MVC Project with the jQuery calling the services.  Both projects were using Cassinni, which inherently is where the real problem happened.  I had the WCF Project on one port and the ASP.NET MVC on another port, but both were running from localhost.  That leads to the [same origin problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).  I setup the entire solution again in a single project (because I'm hard headed and did NOT want to install and run IIS to remove Cassinni as the issue).  I've outlined my entire solution here [tying it all together](http://compositecode.com/2010/09/03/aggregated-web-services-pt-ii-2/).

So to summarize, the code above is actually correct and does indeed work.  The ports however make it fail in any security compliant browser (in other words, non-IE browsers).  It seems that IE likes to ignore the same origin issue, leaving that as a gaping security concern with that browser.  :/

Answer (score 3):

You need to tell jQuery to parse the result as JSON by adding `dataType: 'json'` to the `ajax` parameters..

Comment: I still get undefined for the data when it comes back.  :(

Answer (score 1):

have you tried using json.d or json.data?

Comment: I had not tried them, but did, and I got undefined back from both.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery usually does not send json data as a function parameter when an ajax call is done, and if it sends it, is just string code, which you need to eval. try either one of these ideas:

1- do

```
var j = eval(json);
```

and instead of

```
.append('<td>' + json.Company + '</td>')
```

do

```
.append('<td>' + j.Company + '</td>')
```

or use

```
jQuery.getScript()
```

instead of `jQuery.Ajax()`

I like more the second, since it's the one I use

Comment: I tried the jQuery.getScript() but that is for returning an actual Javascript file and executing it.  I just want to use the JSON results that come back.  So far I know I'm getting them based on the Fiddler Results, but I haven't gotten them to actually print out.

Comment: If you want to use the JSON and print it out, you must place it inside a variable. Try the eval way, I think it will work better

Comment: Do not use eval. It is a huge security risk and any properly designed language should have a way to avoid using it possible. Try using $.parseJSON(data) instead. If it's in an invalid format, that will catch/validate the JSON along with failing on malformed data.

Answer (score 0):

Does your returned object have a name?

So are you doing `MyObj obj = new MyObj();` and then setting properties and then returning that object?

If you are then you need to also factor MyObj in your object so I think, untested, `json.d.MyObj` or just `json.MyObj.propertyName;`